# Generation of pdf from lightning aura component and attach the same to case object

Tags: apex, lightning, aura

I have the requirement like i need to generate the pdf from aura component and the generated pdf should automatically attach to case object.

I tried in following ways :

1. I have created lightning component in which i displayed all the data that is need for pdf.
   the component i have will look like below. it will contain other sections also but sample code i kept.
   Now i want this aura component to render as pdf and automatically attach it to the case object.

Can someone please help me in achieving it?

I tried code which was there in different blogs and nothing worked for my requirement.

### code:

```html
<aura:component controller="testcontroller" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <!-- 
        Using lightning:recordViewForm tag record Id and objectApiName is required to fetch record.
        For custom objects, do check you have __c in the api name
    -->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

 
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.recordId}" objectApiName="Case">
     
        <!-- Using lightning:card tag with a title -->
        <lightning:card title="Case Details">
            <!-- lightning:card body section starts -->
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
                <!-- Forming a grid of two equal columns -->
                <!-- First section starts here -->
                <div class="slds-grid">
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <!-- 
                            Using lightning:outputField Tag with fieldName = Api name of field,
                            if you are using a custom field, do check you have __c in the api name
                         -->
                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="CaseNumber" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:outputField fieldName="Origin" />  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p>
        </lightning:card>
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Being here for 4 years, you really ought to know how to format your own questions properly. Review [how to format using Markdown](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanks for formating......@DerekF Could someone please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to generate a PDF with case details and attach that to the same record.

If that is the use case then we can achieve it on the Visualforce page:

1. Create a Visual force page with renderAs="pdf"
2. Create a respective Apex class to pass the data to the VF page dynamically
3. Create a method to gerenatePDF - Here we need to call the same VF page in that method then pass the data as parameters to the VF page finally create the **Convent Version &  ContentDocumentLink** by using [getContentaspdf()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm)

[Generate A PDF from VF page And Attach to Record](https://bayyabuzz.blogspot.com/2022/06/generate-pdf-from-vf-page-add-as.html)